# Why multiple print instead of just once?

Tags: python

I have an input list of **\n** separated strings (*strings.txt*) that I'm trying to match each one just once to a row in input file (*infilelist.tsv*), and print each line out to a new file (*outfile.tsv*).

My outfile.tsv just has the infilelist.tsv printed the same number of times as input strings I'm searching for rather than just once. What is wrong with my for( for( loops that is improperly just multiplying the infilelist.tsv file rather than single matched lines?

#### Example Script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# gets each line containing string input

inlist = []
with open('strings.txt','r') as inlist:
    inlist = [line.strip() for line in inlist.readlines()]

tsvin = []
with open('infilelist.tsv','r') as tsvin:
    tsvin = [line.strip() for line in tsvin.readlines()]

tsvout = []
for item in inlist:
    for row in tsvin:
        tsvout.append(row)

with open('outfile.tsv', 'w') as outobj:
    outobj.writelines('\n'.join(map(str,tsvout)))
```

#### strings.txt

```
string1
string2
string3
```

#### infilelist.tsv

```
string1\tabc123\tinfo
not_important
string2\tbcd234\tinformation
unimportant
string3\tcde345\tinformacion
less_than_important
```

#### outfile.tsv

```
string1\tabc123\tinfo
string2\tbcd234\tinformation
string3\tcde345\tinformacion
```

Comment: I don't see where you actually show what your problem is. Perhaps you could clarify that?

Comment: The intent of the code is not clear. Can you provide an example of strings.txt and infilelist.tsv and show what you expect outfile.tsv to look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for item in inlist:
    for row in tsvin:
        tsvout.append(row)
```

is a double for-loop. *For each item in `inlist`*, this iterates through each row in `tsvin`.

So this does not just iterate through `tsvin` once, it repeats the iteration `len(inlist)` number of times.

---

Instead, you can achieve the goal with a single iteration through `tsvin`:

```
with open('strings.txt', 'rb') as inlist, open('infilelist.tsv', 'rb') as tsvin, open('outfile.tsv', 'wb') as outobj:
    seen = set([line.strip() for line in inlist])
    for line in tsvin:
        if line.split('\t', 1)[0] in seen:
            outobj.writelines(line)
```

Note that

```
seen = set([line.strip() for line in inlist])
```

is creating a set of all the lines in `inlist`.

```
line.split('\t', 1)[0] in seen
```

splits the lines in `tsvin` on tabs a maximum of 1 time and checks if the first part is in the set `seen`. [Checking membership in a set is `O(1)`](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), while checking membership in a list is `O(n)`. So you can save some time by making `seen` a `set` rather than a `list`.

Comment: Correct, I think that's what's required to do this(?) but it seems to just output every row in tsvin the number of strings/items I have.

Comment: This is excellent, explaining the double for-loop and use of set instead of list.